# Horizontally align 2 divs of different heights and keep wrapping within their respective columns

Tags: css

I need to float the 2 divs together so they align horizontally.  If the div on the right is higher it shouldn't go underneath but should wrap underneath itself.

```
<html>

<style>
#left, #right {float:left; border:1px solid black; margin:10px;}
</style>

<div id="container">

<div id="left">
this is an image, the hight and width can vary
</div>
<div id="right">
this div should never wrap underneath the image.  if it is higher than left image it needs to wrap under itself so the space directly beneath the image is respected
</div>

</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>

<hr>

<div id="left">
this is an image, the hight and width can vary
</div>
<div id="right">
this div should never wrap underneath the image.  if it is higher than left image it needs to wrap under itself so the space directly beneath the image is respected
</div>

</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#left, #right {float:left; border:1px solid black; margin:10px; width:45%;}
```